# How do I fix the overhanging blank area on an image using in html?

Tags: css, wordpress, html, web

Basically, with the following code:

HTML: `<div id="himage"><a href="/mdp/"><img title="MDP!" src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/himage.jpg" width="370" height="190"></a></div>`

CSS: `#himage{width:370px;float:left;border:4px solid #0F651C;}`

I get the following, which is not what I want. It keeps adding this white section just below so the boarder doesn't actually go round the image :/

OUTPUT: https://i.stack.imgur.com/67rCL.png

Any ideas?

Comment: You have provided an image with the end result.
Could you please provide a url to the image itself that you are using.
This way I will be able to see what is wrong with the CSS

Comment: Can you show the original image? Looks like the white is in your image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add `img { display: block; }` or something more specific to your image.

Here's a link to the solution example: http://jsfiddle.net/WvmhX/1/

The reason for this weird behavior is because `<img>` elements are considered [Replaced Elements](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/replacedelements).

From Impressive Web's post ["The Difference Between “Block” and “Inline”"](http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/):

> Basically, these are neither block nor inline. But you might classify them as something closer to inline, but with block-like structure.

Comment: It appears as though that does nothing for me :/

Comment: Are you sure? I added a link to a working example. Please check it out.

Comment: You probably have some other CSS rule overwriting the `img` selector. If you could post a fiddle with your code, I could be of more help.

Comment: I've added an explanation to my answer.